# sh: psql: command not found in Zabbix template

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, postgresql-9.6

There is a template for monitoring PostgreSQL

Zabbix v3.2

Zabbix_agent is installed on another server and monitors PostgreSQL 9.6 there. The host is active in the Zabbix server in the web interface, there are no errors.
Partially zero values ​​from the database are output to the template on the Zabbix server and there are

```
sh: psql: command not found
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP2uu.png)

Comment: Also the output of the command

' zabbix_get -s 127.0.0.1 -k pgsql.ping['-h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres'] '

gives out

' h: psql: command not found '

Comment: usually psql is not in the path for users different from postgres. please check if psql is in the $PATH for the user zabbix

Comment: It helped
'
ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/psql / usr / bin / psql
'

Comment: yes, /usr/bin is in the $PATH

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to execute `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/psql`.

If that postgres directory is not in the `$PATH` env var, then trying just `psql`
won't work and will produce a "command not found" diagnostic.

Either tell Zabbix to execute the full pathname,
or put the postgres directory in Zabbix's PATH,
or choose a directory already in Zabbix's PATH
and add a symlink to it.
For example:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/psql
```